# how to use max function for a range in excel using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

i have a worksheet with some rows and columns

i want to paste maximum values from certain rows iteratively into a cell using vb.net

i write the code but it giving the error

please look in to this problem and guide me

```
           For i3 As Integer = 5 To rows2
                With oWs
                    **.cells(11, i3).formula = "=max(.range(E & i3 &  :  j & i3 ))"**

                End With
            Next
```

highlighted portion showing the error message

please guide me

gvg

Comment: can you please say which error you got using max function?

Comment: i am getting the error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is a spreadhseet formula, not a VBA `application.WorksheetFunction`, so, therefore you need to enter it as text, not as a range - Try this:

```
.cells(11, i3).formula = "=max(E" & i3 & ":J" & i3 & ")"
```

Comment: Glad you got it working!! - Remember to mark the solution as your answer, then.